# CakePHP 3 batched query to reduce memory

Tags: cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.0, query-builder

Laravel Eloquent has a cursor method that allows you to iterate through your database records using a cursor, which will only execute a single query. When processing large amounts of data, the cursor method may be used to greatly reduce your memory usage (see https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#retrieving-models).

CakePHP 3 has an advanced ORM, is there something similar like the cursor method in Laravel? Doesn't seem to be mentioned in the books: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm.html

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what exactly the difference between `cursor()` and non-`cursor()` usage is in Laravel (besides from the obvious), but in CakePHP you're probably looking for `Query::bufferResults()`, respectively `Query::enableBufferedResults()` (as of CakePHP 3.4).

```
$query->bufferResults(false)
```

```
$query->enableBufferedResults(false)
```

Disabling result buffering will stop result sets from being buffered in memory, and for MySQL it will also disable `MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY`.

Unbuffered result sets can only be iterated once, and results cannot be cached/serialized. Also buffering cannot be disabled for queries that contain associations which are being retrieved in a separate query (which is always true for `hasMany` and `belongsToMany`).

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Retrieving Data & Results Sets > Working with Result Sets](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#working-with-result-sets)**
- **[API > \Cake\Database\Query::bufferResults()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/class-Cake.Database.Query.html#_bufferResults)**
- **[API > \Cake\Database\Query::enableBufferedResults()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/class-Cake.Database.Query.html#_enableBufferedResults)**
- **[PHP Manual > MySQL > Buffered and Unbuffered queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php)**